# Bubbling in two children - JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick, event-bubbling

There is large square and small square that the large square is the top layer.
When I click **only** on the large square I want that the click event of the large square will play.
When I click on the small square I want that both of the click events will play.

**I don't want to put one div into another.**

Thanks in advance :-)

The component:

```
function App() {
    const clickOnSmall = () => {
        console.log('SMALL')
    }
    const clickOnLarge = () => {
        console.log('LARGE')
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className={'small'} onClick={clickOnSmall}></div>
            <div className={'large'} onClick={clickOnLarge}></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The CSS:

```
.large {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.small {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 35%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The browser:
[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRQiS.png)

There is large square and small square that the large square is the top layer.
When I click **only** on the large square I want that the click event of the large square will play.
When I click on the small square I want that both of the click events will play.

**I don't want to put one div into another.**

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You cannot do that directly. You could have one "click" handler trigger the other, but managing that would be very complicated. Why not put your handler on the parent `<div>` and have it do everything the two handlers do?

Comment: Why do large need to have a bigger `z-index` ?

Comment: The code here is only a simple example from a large project. In the large code I can't change anything, because of this I can't do what you say.

Comment: What can you change?

Comment: In the HTML nothing, only the function.